# Can I give a third party access to Google Analyticis for a specific page and/or subdomain without disclosing other information

Tags: google-analytics

Working with several agencies who might need access to google analytics, we are wondering whether it is possible to give only access to specific pages or subdomains.

Comment: You can create a custom view with filters to only show those pages or subdomains, and then grant access just to the custom view.